# SUM of columns returning as string instead of integer

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following model:

```
class Goal extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'time_logged_today' => 'integer',
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'time_logged_today'
    ];

    protected function timeLoggedToday(): Attribute
    {
        $time = Record::where('goal_id', $this->id)
            ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
            ->sum('seconds');

        return new Attribute(
            get: fn () => $time,
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, it simply SUMS the `seconds` column from its relationship.

But here is how it's being returned in JSON:

```
{
  "goals": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test1",
      "time_logged_today": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test2",
      "time_logged_today": "2000",
    }
  ]
}
```

It's returning both integers and strings (seems like it returns as an integer when it's zero, and a string otherwise).

How can I always make it return as an integer??

Comment: You can remove the $casts property for this attribute. The sum() function already returns an integer, so there's no need to cast it explicitly.